# Nested "for loop" and "setTimout" JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined, settimeout, nested-loops

I would like to create a function that display and animates text like typewriter. And I need a random timeout between each letter typing and a different timeout between each word. When I start this script the animation works but it is written "undefinedundefinediinundefinedundefined".

I need your help :) thanks !

```
pTyping = document.getElementById("p1");
let textTyping = "Website in construction";
let wordTyping = textTyping.split(" ");

let typing = function (){
    let currentWord ="";
    let rand;
    let timer = 1;

    for(let i = 0; i < wordTyping.length-1; i++){
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function(){
                timer = 1000;
                currentWord = wordTyping[i].split('')
                for(let j = 0; j < currentWord.length-1; j++){
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(4));
                    (function (j){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        pTyping.innerText += currentWord[j]
                        },rand*100+100) 
                    })(j)
                }
            },timer)
        })(i)
    }
}
typing();
```

Comment: I've recently answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64789325/jquery-sequential-functions-one-after-the-other-in-a-each-loop/64790482#64790482